# RSpec double as ActiveJob argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec3, rails-activejob

I need to test a class that submits an ActiveJob using `perform_later` with RSpec doubles as arguments

My class does at some point

```
def register_event!
    MyJob \
    .set(wait_until: event.end_date + 1.day) \
    .perform_later(
      event: event,
      reviewer: event.random_participant,
    )
```

The associated RSpec test

```
let(:event) { create(:event, participants: [participant_double]) }
let(:participant_double) { global_id_instance_double(User) }
let(:job_params) { event: event, reviewer: participant_double }

describe MyClass do 
  it 'creates a Job' do
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :test
    expect { subject.register_event! } \
    .to have_enqueued_job(MyJob) \
    .at(event.end_date) \
    .with(**job_params)
  end
```

I get an error

```
ActiveJob::DeserializationError:
   Error while trying to deserialize arguments: undefined method `find' for RSpec::Mocks::InstanceVerifyingDouble:Class
 # /Users/Cyril/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/globalid-0.4.0/lib/global_id/locator.rb:130:in `locate'
 # /Users/Cyril/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/globalid-0.4.0/lib/global_id/locator.rb:155:in `block in locate'
 # /Users/Cyril/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/globalid-0.4.0/lib/global_id/locator.rb:167:in `unscoped'
 # /Users/Cyril/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/globalid-0.4.0/lib/global_id/locator.rb:155:in `locate'
 # /Users/Cyril/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/globalid-0.4.0/lib/global_id/locator.rb:17:in `locate'
 # /Users/Cyril/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activejob-5.0.2/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:111:in `deserialize_global_id'
 # /Users/Cyril/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activejob-5.0.2/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:97:in `deserialize_argument'
 # /Users/Cyril/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activejob-5.0.2/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:121:in `block in deserialize_hash'
 # /Users/Cyril/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/transform_values.rb:16:in `block in transform_values'
 # /Users/Cyril/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/transform_values.rb:15:in `each'
 # /Users/Cyril/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/transform_values.rb:15:in `transform_values'
 # /Users/Cyril/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activejob-5.0.2/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:121:in `deserialize_hash'
 # /Users/Cyril/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activejob-5.0.2/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:99:in `deserialize_argument'
 # /Users/Cyril/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activejob-5.0.2/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:51:in `block in deserialize'
 # /Users/Cyril/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activejob-5.0.2/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:51:in `map'
 # /Users/Cyril/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activejob-5.0.2/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:51:in `deserialize'
 # ./spec/services/event_booker_service_specs.rb:72:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # /Users/Cyril/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
 # /Users/Cyril/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
 # /Users/Cyril/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
 # /Users/Cyril/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
 # /Users/Cyril/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spring-commands-rspec-1.0.4/lib/spring/commands/rspec.rb:18:in `call'
```

*Note that the line corrsponding to `event_booker_service_specs` points to the code extract `expect { subject.register_event! } \` mentionned above

For information I'm using the code for GlobalID found there : https://gist.github.com/tylerhunt/3decf5a32873625110c1

Comment: You don't need to add backslashes when seperating method calls into multiple lines. The interpreter looks ahead to the next line and can se that it starts with `.`. There is nothing harmful about it though - just looks really strange since its not a common style.

Comment: @max there are already big discussions on the rucobop github and I don't want to discuss that -- this style allows to be copy pasted in a shell (very common when doing devOps or trying stuff in a console, and in that case there is no look ahead) and you still know you're dealing with method chains when looking at individual lines. Sorry if this is a style you don't see very often.

Comment: Can't you just use a real User instance by using `build_stubbed(:user)` instead?

Comment: Well I actually get a very similar error `ActiveJob::DeserializationError` `Document(s) not found for class User with id(s) 59065c33aba9cf2598c8e236`.
I find that really weird... why would `expect{ ... }.to have_enqueued_job` even try to deserialize the job right away ? Isn't serialization enough ? Or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: In the meantime I'll just fall back to using real models with `FactoryGirl.create` but the test suite is really slow (13 secs) so I'd like to use mocks whenever possible

Comment: The problem is there is no `find` method on the Class. Normally, it will think it's an ActiveRecord instance so it could be find by `Class.find(id)`.